# Connect factory exchange open source library issue

Tags: c#, json-serialization

I am creating custom message which is calling executeRequest method of cfxenvelope. It is throwing error
‘Error resolving conflict type path messagebody.$type
This issue is related to Jsonserializer tynamhandling
This issue is in cfx library so cannot try anything
https://github.com/IPCConnectedFactoryExchange/CFX